# How to convert a printer driver to a stand-alone console application which can generate a printer file containing the bytes to be sent to the printer?

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, sdk, printing

I have a situation where the *only* way to generate a certain datafile is to print it manually to FILE: under Windows and save it in a file for further processing.

I would really like to have a small stand-alone program which embeds this binary printer driver so I can run it from a batch file and have it generate that binary file for me, as we can then fully automate the "save file in Visio, 'print' it and upload it to the final destination and trigger a remote test".

Is this possible with a suitable Windows SDK?  I am a Java programmer, so I do not know Visual Studio and the possibilities with MSDN - yet! - but I'd appreciate pointers.

---

EDIT:  I have the installation files for that printer driver, both 32 and 64 bit.  Older versions may include a 16 bit driver.

---

EDIT:  The "print to FILE:" functionality is just what was recommended by the documentation.  I have played a little bit with using the LPR-protocol to see what it can do.  I'd still prefer the "invoke small binary" approach.

Comment: What is the format of the file, is it a text based data file?

Comment: If you can print it manually with Visio, you should be able to use office automation to print to the printer driver. This means you could write a small exe to automate this.

Comment: @Redman, the file could be any Windows print job, as this process converts the Windows print job into a byte stream to be included in a proprietary IBM printing system as a so-called "overlay" (essentially a kind of stationary).

Comment: I think you should ask a question about the 'certain datafile' rather than how to hack a printer driver...

Comment: Is your question "how do I take a Visio file and generate the printer output file from it"?

Comment: @Stobor.  Close:  "Given this Visio file in the file system, how can I programatically print it, and capture the bytes which would have been sent to the printer?".

Comment: @Thorbjørn: Yeah, I skipped the detail, but that was how I read it. Hmm... What you're after is more difficult than you're expecting, and not because of the printer driver stuff... You also need something which will read and understand the Visio file format... The file is not normally passed to the printer driver - instead Visio renders the file to a standard intermediate format, then the result of that is converted by the printer driver into the bytes for the printer which you want to capture...

Comment: Stobor, in that case I can live with "When a user prints any file to this particular Windows printer, then automatically capture the bytes that would have been sent to the printer".

Comment: @Thorbjørn: In your response to Oleg, you mentioned that you are printing from a AFP printer. Had some experiences with AFP printfiles and extraction of text and images. Didn't wrap the printer but processed the files. Updated my answer woth the experiences

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The general problem which you formulate is difficult to solve. Mostly a printer driver consists from some well known components like Print Monitor, Print Processor etc. which are well documented in Windows Driver Kit http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff560885%28v=VS.85%29.aspx. Some years ago I wrote a Print Monitor. It worked many years at a customer. So I know exactly what I writing about. A Print Monitor is nothing more as a DLL with well documented functions. The same is about most other printer components. Those DLLs will be loaded and called from Spooler. If you have a modern printer driver it has no components which run in kernel mode. So **one can load most of DLLs from which consist every printer driver and call corresponding function**.

You are interesting for using **one concert printer driver**. So the first what one should do is to examine **how** this driver is implemented. If you find out which component do the job which you need, you will be probably able to load this DLL in your process and produce output which you need. It is possible that you post an URL where I could download this driver?

**UPDATED**: I though a little more about your requirements. It seems to me you can goes with the way suggested by developer of the printer driver. If the driver can print to a local port FILE, then it can print in **any** printer port. So you can give src of a Port Monitor Server driver from C:\WinDDK\7600.16385.1\src\print\monitors\localmon (see also http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff556478%28v=VS.85%29.aspx, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff549405%28v=VS.85%29.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff563806%28v=VS.85%29.aspx). (I is a windows 32/64 DLL, not a real driver) and makes small modification. Instead of saving results to a file you can dispatch the results to your application. It will be work with 100% without any tricks. If you will have some problem to understand **localmon** I can give you some tips. It is really not complex. The main changes which you have to do is to modify `LcmStartDocPort` `LcmWritePort` `LcmReadPort` `LcmEndDocPort` functions from **localmon.c**. Some easy thing which is distinguish Port DLL from a typical DLL, that instead of exporting all DLL's functions it export only one `InitializePrintMonitor2` with pointers to all other functions.

**UPDATED 2**: One more tip for usage of "Local Port" monitor. If goes in printer configuration, then choose "Add Port...", select "Local Port" and click "New Port..." you can type any file name like "C:\temp\my.bin". Then all what you print through a printer will be printed in this file without any user iteration. The name can be **any** win32 file name (UNC names or Named pipes are also allowed). With this way you can realize some scenarios without any programming with DDK.

**UPDATED 3**: I looked at the printer driver from different sides and looked one more time in the API in DDK. Now I want recommend you to choose the easiest way, and the way which will be full supported from the driver manufacturer. I suggest following:

You install a printer with the driver which you need and choose as the output port a *Local Port* with a fixed file name (see Update 2). I named here the destination filename as *C:\TEMP\Output.afp*. So you receive exactly the same situation like recommend you driver manufacturer. Fixed file name is **absolutely** the same as **FILE:** port. So if you print to the printer you receive in *Output.afp* file in the *C:\TEMP* directory. To be sure the end of writing you can use `ReadDirectoryChangesW` or `FindNextChangeNotification` / `FindFirstChangeNotification` functions with `dwNotifyFilter` equal to `FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_LAST_WRITE`. Then you receive notification after last write-time of the file. It means after the end of writing and after `FileClose` and after the cache is sufficiently flushed. So the file *Output.afp* is not locked and you can really safe read the results.

For printing of simple documents you can use `WritePrinter` function (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162959%28VS.85%29.aspx and remark in the documentation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145226%28VS.85%29.aspx). Writing of complex files with bitmaps, color and different fonts you have to use typical GDI API like one this in Windows (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162865%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

This solution looks not very spectacular like writing a printer driver component or a simulation of spooler environment for printer driver, but it will work, will safe work and will be full supported from the driver manufacturer.

Comment: Ahh, didnt know you could just give it a filename  :) Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @Oleg.  The driver in question is the AFP driver available from http://bit.ly/byiZ8a which apparently creates MO:DCA-P output.

I believe the actual driver is very old, so the interface may be quite simple.

Comment: This post looks like the most complete answer on this topic. I can compile the Localmon example, but have no idea on how I would need to change it for what I need. I need to create driver (or monitor..the lines here are still a bit fuzzy) to generate a PostScript file and send it to a server. I have found code to create a Printer Port but that seems like half the story. Are there any resources that detail what needs to be done to create the INF, dlls required and the port monitor to watch the driver?

Answer (score 7):

(It's been 10 years since I did anything like this, but I don't think the overall concepts have changed all that much:)

What you want to do is implement a custom print processor. A print processor is the piece of code that takes the output that the printer driver generates and transports it to the output device. Print processors are implemented as regular user-mode DLLs. You should be able to find everything you need, including samples, in the Windows DDK.

Comment: I'd like to hear more about this approach.  If anybody has actual experience please create a new answer.

Comment: @Thorbjørn. If you install Windows Driver Kit (WDK) 7.1.0 from http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/DevTools/WDK/WDKpkg.mspx you will an example of Sample Print Processor in the directory **C:\WinDDK\7600.16385.1\src\print\genprint**. Documentation you will find in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff563807%28v=VS.85%29.aspx. See also http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff561035%28v=VS.85%29.aspx to understand the printer architecture.

Answer (score 4):

A while ago we made a commercial application which captured print streams from any windows application and converted the result to XML and tiff images
We did make a prototype with the DDK, but ended up buying a SDK for the print capturing
The SDK was from [BlackIce](http://www.blackice.com/Printer%20Drivers/PrinterDriverProducts.htm). Although it wasn´t a free SDK, the distribution of the runtimes were royalty free.

Implementation was done with Visual C (unmanaged) and VB6.
The printer driver had to be installed on the server/PC that drove the printing process.
I remember that the tricky part was to control the printer settings in runtime (keep the tiffs compressed, output directory for the files, paper size:A4 or Letter and other settings that were defined in the [DEVMODE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183565%28VS.85%29.aspx) print control structure).

**UPDATE:** *(Your comment to @Oleg about MO:DCA P triggered my memory. Although it is not about a printer driver...)*
For our commercial product, we also had to make a customization to convert MO:DCA (AFP) documents to tiffs and XML.
This SDK had to be able to extract both images and ascii text to enable later conversions
Conversion where then made in batch from AFP documents in one folder to XML and tiffs.
We chose to convert the AFP file after it had been printed (not during print).
The SDK is [SnowBound RasterMaster](http://www.snowbound.com/imaging_sdk/rastermaster_overview.html) and is available in different flavours (we used the Windows API with ActiveX, and I see now that it is available for [Java](http://www.snowbound.com/rastermaster_java/java_overview.html))
So if your requirement is to convert an AFP document to someting else (extract images and extract ascii text) you could try out the software from SnowBound. Make sure you also get the [Optional Feature](http://snowbound.com/rastermaster_java/java_features.html) to be able to extract ASCII text from the MO DCA documents.
This software SDK is more expensive, but it did the job.
They offer a trial version [here](http://register.snowbound.com/RasterMasterEvaluationconvertedpage.html).

Comment: Thanks for updating with SnowBound.  I've found this too, and found that their pricing is not well suited for a "start-small"-approach.  Hence this question.

Comment: @Thorbjørn: Yes I agree that their pricing is not well suited for mass market. I wish they would have changed this and especially the runtime fee.

Comment: @Kb, actually it is the other way around.  I want to _create_ AFP documents - not consume them.

Answer (score 3):

At the moment i have one missing link in your explanation, so let me rephrase what i understood:

- You have a special printer driver on your windows system, that is configured to print into a file.
- You like to have a simple batch program that can give something to this printer driver to output a binary file.
- You have a toolchain where this file can be further processed.

Now my missing part is, what do you want to give to your little batch script, so that it produces your binary file? Do you have a Visio file which should be automatically printed through this driver?

If yes, you should take a look into this [little batch script](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/printfiles.php#PrintAny). It is able to take any file with a registered file extension and send it to the default printer with its default settings. By using [these settings](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/2kprintcontrol.php) you are able to change the printer settings within your windows system from a batch file to make your special driver the default one and putting the output into a file.

So if i understood you correctly i didn't had the complete solution but i think a good starting point to accomplish your task.

#### Update

Ok, after reading your comment, i fully understood what you like to achieve. To get this to work you have to follow Per Larsens advice to write your own driver with the windows ddk (or to be more precise the [Windows Driver Kit [WDK]](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/Devtools/wdk/default.mspx)) and encapsulate the already existing driver.

So in short and simple: Your driver signs up as new printer driver. When it is called it gets all the raw bytes from the application. Passes it into the driver that can generate your datafile. Get the output from that driver back and do with it whatever you like.

Some samples to get started can also be found in MSDN as [overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff561097.aspx) or more precisely [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff549904.aspx).

But just to say it right beforehand: This is not an easy or simple task and the effort is quite high. Maybe trying to manipulate the driver settings of your special driver through the already given batches or a simple application (written with [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/index.shtml)) can also solve your problem, by just interacting (automatically) with the settings of the driver.

Comment: This looks very useful for scripting the print process (instead of users having to push print), but does not handle the capturing (which is the crucial part right now).

Comment: But what i still didn't understand is what you like to capture.

Comment: I'd like to capture the bytes generated by the printer driver, which would have been sent to the printer.

Comment: regarding the "this is actually quite hard".  I was aware that that could be the case, but for now I am interested in seeing for my self *how* hard.  Thanks for the dirct pointers to MSDN.

Answer (score 2):

> I can live with "When a user prints any file to this particular Windows printer, then automatically capture the bytes that would have been sent to the printer".

In that case, you want something like [RedMon](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~ghost/redmon/), which redirects the bytes which would have gone to the printer into the input for another program.

Answer (score 2):

Just to reiterate, probably the simplest capture method is using a new Local Port configured as a filename.  You can to monitor the output file as previously discussed to catch the output.

Otherwise, you want to write your own port monitor - not a printer driver or a print processor.  All a port monitor does is receive the already rendered data from the printer driver, and sends it to the output device.  So writing your own port monitor will allow you to go in and change the output port associated with the existing printer driver to be your own output port, and your port monitor can simply write the data to a file, probably one with a unique filename in a dedicated directory.

Printer drivers are far too complicated for what you want to do, and while a print processor could also capture the output data, you'd probably get entangled in some scantily documented system issues you won't want to have to figure out.

The LocalMon sample in the Windows Driver Kit is THE starting point for writing a port monitor.  However, it manages all the system local ports and is quite a bit more complex than you need.  In fact, much of it is just likely to confuse you.  I'd recommend you start with LocalMon, and compare it to the Redmon source, which is much simpler because it manages a dedicated port.  Beware that the Redmon source was taken from localmon long ago and appears to have a few bugs, so use Redmon as a reference and pare back the LocalMon code to what's needed to just write the output to a file.

Answer (score -2):

You don't embed drivers in executables- drivers are for the operating system to communicate with the hardware.

You print via the Operating system.

Your 'batch' needs to select the correct printer, and print...

Comment: understanding a question is the best first step to proposing a solution. the ability to infer intent is a big plus. either way, your answer adds nothing positive to the conversation.