# How to grab print content in Print Monitor API & save it to a file?

Tags: printing, port, monitor, wdk

my requirement:

User click 'Print' button in any software can implement the following jobs:

1. Save the print job to pdf/jpeg/bmp on hard disk.
2. Send this print job to the printer and print.

I am just learning the Print Monitor sample in a few days,  following the msdn's WDK Port Monitor samples, but I don't know where to grab the print content, acorrding to msdn, port monitor send raw data to kernel-mode port driver,

1. I know the LcmStartDocPort() calls CreateFile(), LcmWritePort()
   calls WriteFile(), it seems these 2 function do the communication to
   the "kernel-mode port driver"?
2. it seems I need grab this raw data & save it to the local disk?

Any suggestion? Thank you!

Comment: Hi there is a lot of printer/driver info in this so article-->http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693133/how-to-convert-a-printer-driver-to-a-stand-alone-console-application-which-can-g

Comment: After read your suggested thread, refer to [MSDN Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff561035(v=vs.85).aspx), it seems the Print Porcessor is what I want, I will do some further research.

Comment: There have been no kernel mode components in the print subsystem since NT4. And what you need is a port monitor, not a print processor. Although you could do it with a print processor, that's doing it the hard way. Just be forewarned that version 4 print drivers (Windows 8 only) do not support custom port monitors. There are also many commercial products out there that will save print jobs as PDF.